# How to Add animation to UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there a way to add a flip or a turn animation to a UITextField? I have every thing setup where I press a button to add something to a UITextField. I thought it would be cool if I added some animation. Just wondering if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. Any view can be animated. Though depending on what you're trying to animate from/to, it might be better to place them into a UIView...